# After docker run python starts automatically. how to stop that?

Tags: python, docker, shell

I assemble docker image with a dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.13-slim

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app

RUN apt-get apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libgl1-mesa-glx && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56 && \
    pip install pandas==1.4.3 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
```

but after `docker run -v /home/user/work/test_images/:/app -ti name:tag`
I get started python3, instead of a shell. How to stop that?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the container? Run a script inside of it?

Comment: I assume you want to run bash as the entrypoint, you can calways do `docker run -it --entrypoint bash <image>`

Comment: You could put a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to run bash at the end of the docker file.

Comment: yes, I want to run a ```python run.py /test_images /out_images``` from ```/app``` folder and process some images

Comment: You should put a `CMD ./run.py ...` to run the script as the main container process.

Answer (score 0):

For the Python image in particular (and images based on it), if you want to start a shell instead of Python, just add the shell to the end of your `docker run` command line:

```
docker run -v /home/user/work/test_images/:/app -ti name:tag bash
```

The suggestions in the comments about the use of `--entrypoint` are valid suggestions and solve the general case, but they aren't necessary with the Python image.

---

Of course, you could configure your image to start your Python script by default so that you don't have to manually run `python run.py`.